# The Array is empty - foreach() does not seam to work || The values does not get passed into the loop

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, exceljs

```
const filteredOptions = _.filter(grantedValuesFinal, o => o.numberOfShareOptionAwardGranted > 0);

let filteredArray = []; 
filteredOptions.forEach(function(item, i){
  
  let existing = filteredArray.filter(function(o, i) {
    const dateNew = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(o.grantDate);
    const dateExsisting = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(item.grantDate);

    return o.grantDate == item.grantDate; 
  });

  if (existing.length) {
    let existingIndex = filteredArray.indexOf(existing[0]);
    if(item.typeOfEquity == "Shares") filteredArray[existingIndex].numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedShares += item.numberOfShareOptionAwardGranted;  
    if(item.typeOfEquity == "Options") filteredArray[existingIndex].numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedOptions += item.numberOfShareOptionAwardGranted;  
    
  } else {
      let numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedShares = 0, numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedOptions = 0;
      if(item.typeOfEquity == "Shares") numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedShares += item.numberOfShareOptionAwardGranted; 
      if(item.typeOfEquity == "Options") numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedOptions += item.numberOfShareOptionAwardGranted; 
      filteredArray.push({grantDate: item.grantDate, numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedShares: numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedShares, numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedOptions: numberOfShareOptionAwardGrantedOptions }); 
  }
})
```

**The very first line of the code does not pass any value, due to which filteredOptions and array is empty. What changes has to be done ? Please help**

Comment: The first line should return all the array elements with `numberOfShareOptionAwardGranted > 0`. If you're not getting anything, then that must be false for all `grantedValuesFinal`

Comment: @mjwills The `else` block pushes elements into `filteredArray`, which could then be returned into `existing`.

Comment: Barmar is right, condition `o => o.numberOfShareOptionAwardGranted > 0` should satisfy for any contents in `grantedValuesFinal`, either there is no obj in `grantedValuesFinal` which satisfy this condition or there is problem with `_filter`.

Answer (score 0):

The filteredOptions array always stayed NULL as the grantedValuesFinal was only filtering out NULL values.

I was able to work out the code by placing !=NULL and got the non-null values.
Thank you all for your insights